# Is S^2 x S^4 a complex manifold?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, dg.differential-geometry, open-problems

As observed by [Calabi](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1993108) a long time ago, the manifold $S^2\times S^4$ admits an almost-complex structure (obtained by embedding it in $\mathbb{R}^7$ and using the octonionic product), which however is not integrable.

Is it known whether $S^2\times S^4$ admits an integrable complex structure?

A few remarks.

- This is stated as an open problem in Calabi's paper, but perhaps it has been solved in the meantime?

  This is similar to the case of $S^6$, which is still open (see  [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1973/is-there-a-complex-structure-on-the-6-sphere)).

  One can also ask the same question for $\Sigma\times S^4$ for $\Sigma$ any compact Riemann surface

  It seems that some people believe that every almost-complex manifold of real dimension $6$ or more admits an integrable complex structure (see [this other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52960/which-almost-complex-manifolds-admit-a-complex-structure)).

  Even more generally (and this is obviously still open), one can ask about an arbitrary finite product of even dimensional spheres (excluding $S^0$). [It is known](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s1-40.1.705) that this is almost complex iff the only factors that appear are $S^2, S^6$ and $S^2\times S^4$.

  If one allows connected sums, then for example $(S^2\times S^4)\#2(S^3\times S^3)$ is a complex manifold, and in fact it has complex structures with trivial canonical bundles (see for example [here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1197320602) and [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/gt.2010.14.1723)).

Comment: I thought this question was resolved for $S^6$ a while ago (after the question you link to was posed and answered)? Am I wrong?

Comment: I believe the question for $S^6$ is still open. There are old published papers that claimed to prove that it is not complex (and the general consensus is that these are wrong), and there is a preprint by Etesi on the arXiv that claims that it is complex (and I don't know anybody who has read it carefully). 

Comment: As an aside, it is a *very weak* condition for an oriented $6$-manifold $X$ to admit an almost complex structure (compatible with the orientation. Namely, this is equivalent to the existence of a complex spin structure, i.e. the vanishing of the Bockstein of second Stiefel-Whitney class $W_3=\beta w_2=0 \in H^3(X,\mathbb{Z})$. In particular, no 2-torsion in $H^3(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is enough. Moreover, the almost complex structures up to homotopy form an affine space under $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$, by obstruction theory. For instance, there is a unique structure up to homotopy on $S^6$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is still an open problem. See [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.6835) for some progress, which was prompted by this MO question.